# Get precision and recall value with Tensorflow CNN classifier

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, classification, precision-recall

I was wondering if there was a simple solution to get recall and precision value for the classes of my classifier?

To put some context, I implemented a 20 classes CNN classifier using Tensorflow with the help of  Denny Britz code : https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf .

As you can see at the end of text_cnn.py he implements a simple function to compute the global accuracy :

```
# Accuracy
        with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
            correct_predictions = tf.equal(self.predictions, tf.argmax(self.input_y, 1))
            self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, "float"), name="accuracy")
```

Any ideas on how i could do something similar to get the recall and precision value for the differents categories?

Maybe my question will sound dumb but I'm a bit lost with this to be honest. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Precision and recall are not defined for a multiclass classifier, only for a binary one.

Comment: I'm not sure i agree since precision is the fraction of elements which were  correctly declared of class "i" out of all instances where the algorithm declared "i". Conversely, recall is the fraction of events where we correctly declared "i" out of all of the cases where the true of state of the world is "i". So wether you have 2 classes or more does not change much for the computation of recall and precision per class. But maybe you meant they are not defined for multiclass classifier in tensorflow? then it's my bad :p

Comment: Oh, yes you are right, its still binary but it can be applied to multiclass, I guess you can use tf.contrib.metrics.confusion_matrix to get the confusion matrix and then compute precision/recall from that.

Comment: Okay i will check it out. Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 3):

Using tf.metrics did the trick for me :

```
#define the method
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, )
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, )
acc, acc_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=x, predictions=y)
rec, rec_op = tf.metrics.recall(labels=x, predictions=y)
pre, pre_op = tf.metrics.precision(labels=x, predictions=y)

#predict the class using your classifier
scorednn = list(DNNClassifier.predict_classes(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(testing_set)))
scoreArr = np.array(scorednn).astype(int)

#run the session to compare the label with the prediction
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
v = sess.run(acc_op, feed_dict={x: testing_set["target"],y: scoreArr}) #accuracy
r = sess.run(rec_op, feed_dict={x: testing_set["target"],y: scoreArr}) #recall
p = sess.run(pre_op, feed_dict={x: testing_set["target"],y: scoreArr}) #precision

print("accuracy %f", v)
print("recall %f", r)
print("precision %f", p)
```

Result :

```
accuracy %f 0.686667
recall %f 0.978723
precision %f 0.824373
```

Note : for Accuracy I would use :

```
accuracy_score = DNNClassifier.evaluate(input_fn=lambda:input_fn(testing_set),steps=1)["accuracy"]
```

As it is simpler and already compute in the evaluate.

Also call variables_initializer if you don't want cumulative result.

Comment: How does this work given DNNClassifier is a class not an instance and therefore has no self, as in: TypeError: predict_classes() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' How do you initialize the DNNClassifier?

Comment: Follow this example :
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNClassifier